# How to use str_replace in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**how to use php function str_replace in laravel framework.**

My array key names on table columns name so keys have '_' like first_name, last_name etc. i want to remove these '_' in blade file. my requirement is string replace in .blade.php file.

i am trying this php code but it's useless.

```
<th>{{str_replace('_', ' ', $str)}}</th>
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "useless"? I see no reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: It works. My guess is `$str` is undefined or empty.

Comment: You may want to actually make them camel case instead ("firstName" instead of "firstname").  See the Laravel camel_case() function for that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use php code in .blade.php file

try like this

```
<th> <?=str_replace('_', ' ', $str)?> </th>
```

Answer (score 37):

Which version of Laravel did you use?

For laravel 5.x, use this

```
{!! str_replace('_', ' ', $str) !!}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$string = 'The event will take place between ? and ?';

$replaced = Str::replaceArray('?', ['8:30', '9:00'], $string);

// The event will take place between 8:30 and 9:00
```

For Blade

```
 $item = "Free-Active";
{{ Str::replaceArray('free-', [''], $item) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 8 you can use the String Helper function:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

<th>{{ Str::replace('_', ' ', $str) }}</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this

```
<th>{{-- */ echo str_replace('_', ' ', $str); /* --}}</th>
```

OR

```
<th>{{-- */ $data = str_replace('_', ' ', $str); /* --}} {{$data}}</th>
```