# new line text causing error in javascript 'unterminated string literal'

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel-4

I am working with laravel, I have string like this in database,

```
hello
username, address
country
```

Username and country is in new line, and fields type is 'text' in database,

When i am trying to get that into `JavaScript` variable like this,

```
var add="{{ $data['order']->address }}";
```

Getting error `unterminated string literal`. No error if string in 1 line in database.

Comment: You can replace the newlines to empty string and then put to the var add. ri8:

Comment: But for replace string, i have to store that into variable, and when i am trying to store it into variable then getting error.

Comment: can you call a function in javascript before assigning to a variable like var add="{{ removeNewline($data['order']->address) }}";

Comment: no, getting error @Plum

Comment: whats this $data['order']->address variable, is it php

Comment: yes @Plum, using laravel 4

Comment: Could you post some more code leading to var add="{{ $data['order']->address }}";

Comment: that has same sting as i mentioned question. I have one textarea and i am inserting valus using `enter` key and storing into database, then i am retriving that address into javascript like this.

Comment: Can't you do a server-side replace on the `$data['order']->address` variable to change newline characters to `\n`, escaping the backslash if necessary in php/laravel, so that the response that the browser sees is `var add="hello\nusername,\naddress\ncountry"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First option

You can use ES6 and the new string notation:

```
var str = `my
           multiline
           string`;
```

## Second option

Replace newlines with `\n` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27774653/2044039):

```
var add="<?=str_replace("\n", '\n', $data['order']->address)?>"
```

Comment: getting laravel error `syntax error, unexpected '{' ... var add="<?php echo $data['order']->address|replace({'\n':'\n'}); ?>"; `

Comment: failed if i hit 'return' key from `mac`. is it generating any different text?

Comment: yes after using this code getting above error when using '\r'